# Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

we know that the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $f(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} e^{-2\pi i x y} dx $ . Here is the idea used in my textbook, for y<0 :

We calculate the integral above over the semicircle of center 0, and radius R, above the real line. The integral equals $ \int _{-R}^{R} \frac{1}{1+x^2} e^{-2\pi i x y} dx + \int _{\mathcal R} \frac{1}{1+x^2} e^{-2\pi i x y} dx $, where $\mathcal R$ is the circular arc from -R to R . Then:

1) We bound the integral  $ \int _{\mathcal R} \frac{1}{1+x^2} e^{-2\pi i x y} dx $ using the usual M-L inequality trick, to obtain $ |\int _{\mathcal R} \frac{1}{1+x^2} e^{-2\pi i x y} dx | < \frac{A}{R}$, for some A>0. So as R goes to infinity, this integral goes to zero.

2) We know that the overall integral over the semicircle is $ Res (\frac{1}{1+x^2} e^{-2\pi i x y} )$ evaluated at $ i$, the only singularity in the upper half plane. This residue equals $\pi e^{2\pi y}$ .

3)It then follows, when we take $ R \mapsto \infty$, that our integral, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} e^{-2\pi i x y} dx $, equals $\pi e^{2\pi y} $.

My question is: why does the argument above fail when $ y>0 $? where did we use the fact that $ y<0 $, and why do we need to use the lower semicircle centered at zero (and thus the singularity $-i$ when dealing with the case $y>0$ ?

I believe that somewhere in step 1 we use the fact that $y$ is negative, but I can't figure out where. I would appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because
$$
\big|e^{-2i\pi xy}\big|=e^{2\pi y \;\mbox{Im} \;x}.
$$
So $\big|e^{-2i\pi xy}\big|\leq 1$ on the upper semi-circle when $y<0$. And the same holds on the lower semi-circle when $y>0$. Either way when $y=0$.

So your ML uniform estimate 1) relies on this choice. You would not get a constant $A$ if you were doing it the other way around. This part of the integrand would not be uniformly bounded.